# Error using igraph command erdos.renyi.game

Tags: r, igraph

The issue I am having is that for an assignment for a network analysis class I need to use the `erdos.renyi.game` command from the igraph package for R. 
This command looks like this:

```
erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m, type=c("gnp", "gnm"),
                 directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE, ...)
```

Unfortunately, it does not matter what I fill in for n or m (I need m), type, or directed, I always get the same error:

> Error in .Call("R_igraph_erdos_renyi_game", as.numeric(n),
>   as.numeric(type1),  :    At games.c:585 : Invalid probability given,
>   Invalid value

The people around me in class used the exact same code as I did, and for them it worked. So could anyone please help me with this, because I am not really sure what is going on, and the teacher did not understand it either?

Comment: Can you post the code that you're trying into the body of your question, formatting it accordingly please? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [proding a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). You should provide the exact code that you tried (including loading the required packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the 2nd value, which you pass on to `erdos.renyi.game`, is not a numeric value between `0` and `1`:

```
library(igraph)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(erdos.renyi.game(10, p=1))
plot(erdos.renyi.game(10, p=.5))
plot(erdos.renyi.game(10, p=0))

erdos.renyi.game(10, p=10)
# Error in .Call("R_igraph_erdos_renyi_game", as.numeric(n), as.numeric(type1),  : 
#   At games.c:585 : Invalid probability given, Invalid value
```

For example, `10` is greater `1` and therefore not a valid probability.

Comment: The function is a bit confusing. I just read that you need `m`, not `p` - in that case you have to change the `type` parameter: `g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, p.or.m=2, type="gnm")`. `2` is the number of desired edges.